# Dual graphics cards in Mint & Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, multi-monitor

I have a triple boot machine with Windows 7, Mint 13 (with XFCE) and Ubuntu 12. Only under Windows 7 does my second screen attached to a second graphics card come on. Under both Mint and Ubuntu, the second screen is blank and under my display properties I only seen on screen (the second screen enters power saving mode because it is receiving no signal).

They both show up under `lshw` (as well as the on-board GPU on my motherboard but I don't wish to use this).

Do I need to 'tweak' something specifically in Mint or Ubuntu to enable a second GPU?

```
*-pci:0
     description: PCI bridge
     product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1
     bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
     version: 09
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
   *-display
        description: VGA compatible controller
        product: GT218 [GeForce 210]
        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        version: a2
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
        configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
        resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
   *-multimedia
        description: Audio device
        product: High Definition Audio Controller
        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        physical id: 0.1
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
        version: a1
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list
        configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
        resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
*-pci:1
     description: PCI bridge
     product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1.1
     bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
     version: 09
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:41 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f4000000-f50fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
   *-display
        description: VGA compatible controller
        product: GT218 [GeForce 210]
        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
        version: a2
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
        configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
        resources: irq:17 memory:f4000000-f4ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f5000000-f507ffff
   *-multimedia
        description: Audio device
        product: High Definition Audio Controller
        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        physical id: 0.1
        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
        version: a1
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list
        configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
        resources: irq:18 memory:f5080000-f5083fff
*-display
     description: Display controller
     product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 09
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:56 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

[image: Mint display properties]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the two monitors are using the nvidia cards `# nvidia-xconfig -a` as root would:

```
 -a, --enable-all-gpus
       Configure an X screen on every GPU in the system.
```

nvidia-xconfig man page.

edit: Assuming you are using nvidia's driver and not nouveau.

Comment: This was part of it, I also had to enable the second screen via the NVIDIA config utility which I was n't doing either, thanks!

Comment: Followup, I also had to enable Xinerama on my NVIDIA config utility; http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/1333/xinerama.png